# How do i get a gif snapshot of a pdf page

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, itext

I need to get a snapshot of a pdf page and store it as a '.gif' file.(just to let the user preview the file on mouse hover before opening it).
Can this be done using "itextsharp"? Or is there a more efficient way of doing this?
I saw SDK's like "PDF Extractor" which let me capture images 'inside' the pdf page, but nothing that lets me take a snapshot/preview of the pdf page.
Can somebody please provide some insight in to this. I would highly appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will need to use a Raster Image Processor (RIP) like Ghostscript or other interpreter like something from www.tallcomponents.com

Comment: sorry for the late response....I used the tool "PDFRasterizer" from www.tallcomponents.com. I was able to extract the 1st page of the pdf in to a gif file. But the image was of very low quality. I am yet to explore if there is a way to increase the dpi on the image. Any suggestions?